# Why does a VPN hinder connection to a public wifi with a login?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

When I'm on my VPN and connect to a public wifi that has a registration or login (Amtrack, airports, some cafes and libraries) it takes a long time and many failed webpage loads before it eventually works and brings up the login window, typically 15 minutes or more.

I've tried everything [here](https://zapier.com/blog/open-wifi-login-page/), as well as a separate tip to try accessing 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS) from a webbrowser.  None of these ideas seem to help — but turning off the VPN works immediately.

Why is it that the VPN hinders this detection? And is there a (safe) workaround besides closing network apps and temporarily disabling the VPN?

I'm on a Mac, but asking here, because I suspect this is an OS-independent phenomenon.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the VPN before doing the logon? If so, why not logon first?

Comment: @harrymc, both because I'm usually running the VPN already at all times (so turning it off and reauthenticating is inconvenient) and because applications like Mail and web browsers may transmit unprotected info before I get the VPN restarted.  Given what I've learned here, I'll close apps and the VPN in order to get online, and then turn the VPN back on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it that the VPN hinders this detection? And is there a (safe) workaround besides closing network apps and temporarily disabling the VPN?

Wi-Fi networks with browser-based login pages (aka "captive portals") work by intercepting plain HTTP requests, as well as plain DNS queries, and making the response redirect to the local network's login webpage instead of the real server you wanted.

But when you're connected to a full-tunnel VPN, those requests are not visible to the local network anymore – they're tunnelled inside the encrypted VPN connection. Indeed, for many people **the whole point of using a VPN** is to prevent interception by local networks.

Of course, most networks actually block all non-HTTP traffic until you log in, so the VPN-tunnelled requests end up going nowhere. Quite possibly those 15 minutes are what it takes for your VPN software to give up and close the tunnel entirely.

An OS could work around this by having a dedicated captive-portal detection service which tests each interface individually, bypassing the system's routing table (e.g. NetworkManager on Linux does this) – and then opening the login webpage in such a way that it bypasses the VPN as well. (Of course, bypassing the VPN is often undesired and many "privacy-oriented" VPN apps try all sorts of things to prevent it anyway.)

Other than that, there's no real workaround as long as all of your web browsing goes through the VPN.

Comment: Even if your OS has captive portal detection built-in, and even if you don't have a super-strict full-tunnel VPN policy in place,  some captive portal Wi-Fi networks specifically work to defeat the OS's built-in captive portal detection, often for nefarious purposes. I've had one captive portal network vendor straight-up admit to countermeasures because they want to force you to launch a real browser so they can read or plant cookies in your real browser in order to better track you. (F*ck those guys.)

Answer (score 1):

As a remark : Signing-on to a public WiFi when you have a VPN already running
will not work.

You should turn the VPN off while signing on to the public WiFi, then, only
when you have the internet, turn it back on.

There is no need to stop all applications, except ones that have problem with this
scenario. In my experience, the operating system in all the cases I
encountered will automatically use the new internet for new connections.

Only programs that keep open connection forever will have a problem, but there
are not many that do so, as this is contrary to good practice.
Most websites will disconnect connections that are left open for too long.

Or, as noted by user Arjan, if some running program is continuously making
connections in the background, which may fall in the short period between
establishing the public WiFi connection and that of the VPN.

Comment: Small aside: _"There is no need to stop all applications"_: except for programs that may use background data which you don't want to go over the temporary non-VPN connection.

Comment: Echoing @Arjan, when you say "no need", I'm not sure if you're considering the security reasons why the VPN would be on.  It's a good point though, to note that there's not usually an issue with failed connections for those applications, just unsecure data.

Comment: Normally there wouldn't be any such applications. I do not myself allow such background applications on my computer. If the poster has any such app, he can selectively stop only it.

Comment: @harrymc, I usually run various communications software that accesses the network on some regular cadence without my explicit go-ahead (Mail, Jabber, Slack, web browsers pinging even from background tabs).

Comment: No choice then, you need to close those that can reveal sensible information or access tokens.